# Search a Number pattern

Tags: php, string, phone-number, text-search

I want to search a phone number from a whole sentence. It can be any number with a pattern like (122) 221-2172 or 122-221-2172 or (122)-221-2172 by help of PHP where I don't know in which part of the sentence that number is exists or I could use substr.

Comment: Learn regular expressions, mate.

Comment: Can you show the pattern of phone number.?

Comment: Thats the problem because the phone number can be 123-123-1234 or (123) 123-1234 or (123)-123-1234 or 123 123 1234. anything

Comment: @sashkello. With my knowledge I couldn't do it or else I wouldn't ask this question here.

Comment: @Soumya I believe that my response is a solution to your problem, but I don't know php...

Comment: @Soumya Then post your previous attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to solve this.  Not 100% on php syntax, but I imagine it would look something like:

```
$pattern = '/^\(?\d{3}\)?-\d{3}-\d{4}/';
```

`^` says "begins with"
`\(` escapes the `(`
`\(?` say 0 or 1 `(`
`\d{x}` says exactly `x` numbers

You may also want to check out [Using Regular Expressions with PHP](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $text = 'foofoo 122-221-2172 barbar 122 2212172 foofoo ';
$text .= ' 122 221 2172 barbar 1222212172 foofoo 122-221-2172';

$matches = array();

// returns all results in array $matches
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{3}[\s][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{3}[\s][0-9]{3}[\s][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{9}|[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{4}/', $text, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];

var_dump($matches);
```